# Printf not Printing the output

Tags: c++, c

Why is this program not printing any output.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int c, i, nwhite, nother;
    nwhite = nother = 0;
    int ndigit[10];

    for(i=0; i<10; ++i)
        ndigit[i] = 0;

    while((c = getchar()) != EOF)
        if( c >= '0' && c <= '9')
            ++ndigit[c-'0'];
        else if(c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t')
            ++nwhite;
        else
            ++nother;

    for(i=0; i<10; ++i)
        printf("%d\n",ndigit[i]);
    printf("%d - %d", nwhite, nother);
}
```

Input: It goes on getting the input upto EOF.

Comment: So, have you tried entering some input and an `EOF`?

Comment: http://barbsbitsnbytes.com/pics/hammerd.jpg

Comment: @SakthiKumar yes. EOF is -1, i tried it but it doesnt work still.

Comment: @HansPassant How should i take your comment ?

Comment: Try typing control-d, or possibly control-z.

Comment: @rcomp, The value of `EOF` in C is -1. The EOF character itself is not "-1".

Comment: Whats the value of EOF?, you are comparing input character(1 byte) with value of EOF. so if EOF is -1 then how can it be a char? char is of only 1 byte whereas "-1" is more than 1 byte.change value of EOF to some single character and try e.g.  while((c = getchar()) != 'E')

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for(i=0; i<10; ++i)
        printf("%i\n",ndigit[i]);
    printf("%i - %i", nwhite, nother);
```

Comment: It still gets on getting the input.

Comment: @rcomp try entering `Ctrl + D` which is the `EOF` after some characters of input

Comment: @rcomp if u r in windows u have to press `Ctrl + Z`